# Optimal browser side image resizing?

Tags: javascript, css, image-processing

Based on code over internet I'm doing image resizing on browser side. I use a `canvas` and so I obtain a new png back from some simple resizing.

This is what I'm trying:

```
const MAX_SIZES = {
  thumbnail: {
    MAX_WIDTH: 200,
    MAX_HEIGHT: 160
  },
  small: {
    MAX_WIDTH: 400,
    MAX_HEIGHT: 300,
  },
  medium: {
    MAX_WIDTH: 800,
    MAX_HEIGHT: 600
  }
};

export const resize = (file, size) => {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
let _this = this;

const { MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT } = MAX_SIZES[size];
let img = document.createElement("img");
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
  img.src = e.target.result;

  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  let width = img.width;
  let height = img.height;

  if (width > height) {
    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
      height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
      width = MAX_WIDTH;
    }
  } else {
    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
      width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
      height = MAX_HEIGHT;
    }
  }
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

  resolve(dataURItoBlob(canvas.toDataURL("image/png")));
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

});

}

So I'm facing these issues:

- Resizing process is *quite slow*.
- Medium images (800x600) get a huge file size, sometimes even more than original.
- In general I get an image with increased bright / color (this is only an appreciation)

So, I wonder if I could take any *cheap* strategies to improve my resizing alternatives. I even would be interested in any PNG image optimization to avoid big files.

Answer (score 0):

for problems like these, I usually resolve to using an existing solution/service for real-time image processing.
https://www.imgix.com/

Answer (score 0):

For **browser-side image resizing and compression** I can recommend a particular javascript library called **Load-Image** which enables you to easily crop, compress and resize images via JavaScript.

https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image

I have done some research because of a project I am working and apparently even 2 Years after your question there still seems to be no standard way of resizing images on the browser side. But the mentioned library should do the trick.